# Azure Schema Registry: SAS authorization

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Is there any possibility to communicate with Azure Schema Registry through REST API using Shared Access Signature token(not Bearer token) for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema Registry only supports OAuth2 and RBAC as authorization.